# Scalikejdbc result set iterator

Tags: scala, jdbc, iterator, scalikejdbc

I'm using scalikejdbc to access a huge table. My understanding stand - it fetches all rows into memory before I can map or iterate over them.

Currently I have an implementation using rxscala Observable, which is very simple. But the receiver is slower than reading sql, and then I get OutOfMemory because of buffering. Here is my current producer as could observable:

```
  def fetchProductsAsObservable(
    sql: SQL[Nothing,NoExtractor],
    extractor: (WrappedResultSet) => ProductItem)
  ) =
    Observable[ProductItem](o =>
      try {
          sql.foreach(row => o.onNext(extractor(row)))
          o.onCompleted()
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => o.onError(e)
      }
    )
```

I'm aware of SQL.foreach method, but it gets an callback method and returns Unit. 
My background is in .NET. Can't figure out myself how to implement properly a simple Iterator in scala with scalikejdbc, which I can give around for parallel processing?

Comment: Care to show part of your code?

Comment: sure, edited the question

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not related to the ScalikeJDBC behavior but to RxJava.
Since your Observable is alimented by a hot source you need to use a backpressure strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the late answer. My actual Backpressure strategy was to use an iterator. ScalaRx is here just because it was the only what I could port from my .NET brain to scala. In the time I have written own little reactive stream. And scalikejdbc 3.x added own scalikejdbc-streams library, which also would not help in my case hovewer.